# How can I tell which picture box is clicked in a 2D array of pictureboxes?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

In this code, I set the image of each picture-box in the array Pboxes(,) and also add a handler for when it is clicked.

```
For x = 0 To Pboxes.GetLength(0) - 1
        For y = 0 To Pboxes.GetLength(1) - 1
            Pboxes(x, y).Image = My.Resources.unrevealed
            AddHandler Pboxes(x, y).Click, AddressOf PictureBoxClicked
        Next
Next
```

In the PictureBoxClicked Sub, I am struggling to find a method to extract the exact index of which picture-box in the 2D array was clicked.

Would appreciate any help :)

Comment: Do you need the index then? Because the `sender` of the click event can be casted to the `PictureBox` that raised the event.

Comment: Otherwise I'd create a custom control that inherits from the original PictureBox, which includes a property telling it's index.

Comment: . . .or even, no need to inherit if you use the tag

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am quite new to vb.net. I just added a tag and extracted sub strings from the tag which represented the index of each dimension of the array.